# Querying a collection of collection using Linq

Tags: .net, linq

I have a nested collection of collection of array that can go to any level I have to query based on a particular id and get the details of that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need a recursive function. I wrote an extension method to `IEnumerable` called `SelectRecursive` on codeproject a while ago:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/80746/Select-Recursive-Extension-method

Usage: `var allChildren = node.ChildNodes.SelectRecursive(n => n.ChildNodes);`